# how to allow only requests from certain GAE apps to an GCE load balancer?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

Let's say I have a group of VM's on GCE (database cluster) behind an HTTP/HTTPS Load balancer:

```
HTTP Load Balancer 
       |
      /|\
  VM1 VM2 VM3
```

It is possible to limit requests only from certain GAE apps?

My goal is to share the cluster with more than one app running in GAE, let's say a trusted zone so that I can avoid an authentication layer on the cluster, GCE side.

Or any idea of how to achieve something similar ?

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine gives you a few methods to identify the GAE app that is doing a request (more information [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/appidentity/)).

Unfortunately, those won't work at the protocol levels currently supported by the Load Balancer and so you'll need to do the authentication in your instances.